# Placeholder left margin/padding on Angular Material datepicker?

Tags: css, angular, datepicker, angular-material

It's easy to set a left margin/padding on the Angular Material Datepicker value just adding `padding-left: xx` on the `input`'s css:

[image: Successs]

> But is it possible to add left margin to the datepicker's
>   placeholder?

I would like to have a bigger margin so that the validation symbol does not hide the placeholder's text:

[image: Error]

Comment: can you add some demo stackblitz of your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to add left margin to datepicker placeholder you need to add the following code in your css

```
<mat-form-field class="my-class">

::ng-deep .my-class .mat-form-field-label{
   padding-left: 20px;
}
```

**Note:** Without using **::ng-deep** your padding left will **not** have any effect not even for 10 or 15px.

Answer (score 0):

You can target `mat-form-field-label` add some custom class to your wrapper element(exmple:-`<mat-form-field class="custom-field">`
) and add following styles in style.css

```
.custom-field .mat-form-field-label{
padding-left: 10px;
}
```

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datepicker-9u5dg8)

Comment: Your demo is not working. You need to add `::ng-deep` before your css class selector

Comment: @SudiptoMukherjee can you explain `not working` bcs demo contains datepicker with padding left on place holder and that's what OP want

Comment: Increase `padding-left: 80px` in your demo. You will see no effect. Then add `::ng-deep .custom-field... ` you will see the change

Comment: @SudiptoMukherjee I understand but i don't think OP need to increase padding more than 10-15 px.anyway thanks for your advice